# Spring Boot facing problem with jstl (JSP)

Tags: spring-boot, jstl

I am working with Spring boot with jstl problem when i call the jsp page it return the error of validation

```
[2m[nio-9090-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV and jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createValidator(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:429) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:487) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1444) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:245) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:396) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:396) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
```

i have install the maven dependency as mentioned below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>   
</dependency>
```

But it still returns the error mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

The error message indicates that there is a conflict between the JSTL implementation provided by the application and the JSTL implementation provided by the container. The application is using the JSTL 1.2 implementation, while the container is using the Jakarta JSP Taglib API (jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext) implementation.

To resolve this issue, you can either upgrade the JSTL implementation provided by the application to Jakarta JSP Taglib API or downgrade the container to one that supports JSTL 1.2.

Remove the JSTL 1.2 dependency from the application's pom.xml file.
Add the Jakarta JSP Taglib API dependency to the application's pom.xml file.
Update the JSTL taglib declaration in the JSP pages to use the Jakarta JSP Taglib API URI.
Here is an example of how to update the JSTL taglib declaration:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://jakarta.servlet.jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Once you have either upgraded the JSTL implementation provided by the application or downgraded the container, you should be able to run your JSP pages without encountering the ClassCastException.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As you mentioned i remove taglib in pom.xml and add this dependency as <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
</dependency> aslo add <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://jakarta.servlet.jsp/jstl/core" %> to my jsp file but still returned the error..

Comment: Error detail are Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://jakarta.servlet.jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:301) ~

Comment: i have another question Will i download the jstl-1.2 manually download and attach to WEB-INF\lib folder or it is not requied??

Comment: The taglib URI in this answer is wrong. See abovelinked duplicate for the correct one.